# How is the verb “singen” used in different tenses?

Tags: english-to-german, preposition, tense

I have read that "Gesang" translates to "singing" in English. But is that the present tense?

The sentence that I am working on is:

> Sing to yourself

So I would like to know the context in which the different variations are used in regards to time. Like "Did you sing to yourself" would be asking about a past action.

So far with using a dictionary I have the phrase translated to

> Singen, die sich selbst

Comment: *Gesang* is a substantive.

Comment: So is "Singerei" and, when capitalized, "Singen".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case just looking up words in a dicitonary without looking closely at context may be confusing indeed.

The example you gave also is a good example of how this confusion can arise. Of course does *Gesang* translate to *singing* but in this case it is not the English present continuous of *to sing* but it is the noun *the singing*.

To overcome this we should have a dictionary providing some context or possible variations where it comes clear that we are looking for different forms and inflection. A good overview on [inflection of *singen* can be found at canoonet.eu](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?input=singen&features=(Cat%20V)(Aux%20haben)&dispatch=inflection&lang=en).

Then it may come clear that "sing to yourself" needs the imperative form of *singen*. Hence a literal translation may be

> Sing(e) zu dir selbst.

However this is not very idiomatic. Looking at the English to German translation of [*"to sing to sb"*](https://www.dict.cc/?s=sing) we will find the different verb *vorsingen* in the list. Hence the following translation will go better:

> Singe dir selbst vor.

We will have to look up the inflection of *[vorsingen](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/vorsingen:V:haben)* then to get it right in different tenses.

Comment: Wäre auch *singe vor dir selbst* richtig? Es erscheinen ja auch da in der Liste beide *jdm vor|singen* und *vor jdm singen* (ganz unterschiedlich, zumindest grammatisch: denn "Ich habe vor, meiner Freundin vorzusingen" ist nicht gelich "Ich habe vor, vor meiner Freundin zu singen"). Ok, vielleicht könnte ich das in einem neuen Beitrag stellen.

Comment: @c.p.: ja, es gibt noch viele andere Möglichkeiten (z.B *singen für*, *singen mit*, ...). Es ist also noch Platz für weitere Antworten ;)

Comment: I really do not understand why you protect this question other than because you like the answer you gave based on the title you gave. How did you arrive at that title anyway? It has nothing to do with the question, the text of the question does not make it clear what is being asked and other questions have been closed for less. I really would appreciate a comment on this.

Comment: @Emanuel: it was not me who closed other questions for less. Because of recent closings and downvotings there is considerable confusion whether beginners questions are welcome or not. That's why we **need** a Meta discussion. From what we had defined up to now this question here showed research effort, and it is clear enough that both, you and me came to the conclusion that *"vorsingen"* is the missing verb here. Easy to answer, but does this make the question bad? It is well within the scope we had defined for a beginner's question. Note that we also have many worse (but upvoted) questions.

Comment: @Takkat... I see your point but please. I quote OP: "So I would like to know the context in which the different variations are used in regards to time. " What does that mean? What does that have to do with anything? Is OP wondering if different tenses want different prepositions? Or is he wondering whether "Gesang, Singerei etc" are needed for different tenses. The question as it is now is an editing ruin. I don't have a problem with beginner questions but I want to be able to understand the question. I am okay with the current title though, so I'll retract my close vote.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to exemplify in one (incomplete) sentence the spectrum of prepositions that *singen* could accept:

> Gestern haben wir **vor** vielen Menschen **wärend** des Abendessens **dank** der Großzügikeit Herrn *X* **für** {*eine Hochzeit · Gott · den Teufel*} <sub><sub>(je nach deinem Geschmack)</sub></sub> (...) gesungen.

Comment: There is also "auf" "von" "über" "um" "hinter" "neben" "während" and more... and they all work with "singen"

Comment: @Emanuel Ja wohl. Da hast du Recht. Ergo beschränke ich mich jetzt auf *vor*. Die andere sind einfach anderer Art. Ich kann das nicht erklären, aber es existiert doch einen Unterschied zwischen *"Ich arbeite an einem Tisch" so, der Zimmerman* und *"ich arbeite auf einem Tisch" so, der/die Stripper(in).* Die Präp. **an** gehört kanonisch zu *arbeiten*, wohingegen **auf** nicht.

Comment: "singen vor" ist nicht "cannonischer" als "singen um" oder "singen hinter"... es ist einfach nur eine Angabe. Es gibt nunmal das Wort "vorsingen".

Comment: @Emanuel Na ja, wenn wir uns auf die Bedeutung *sing. to somebody* beschränken, ist es schon *die* Präposition – zumindest laut dict.cc. Aber wir können das immer, wenn du anderer Meinung bist. Wörterbücher haben auch ja Fehler. Außerdem wie kann eine Frage beantwortet werden, wenn der Titel so schwankend ist? Worauf soll man antworten?

Comment: meiner Ansicht nach sollt man auf den Inhalt der Frage antworten, nicht auf den Titel. Und der Inhalt ist mir unklar, deshalb habe ich "close" gevoted. Was "vor" angeht, stimme ich nicht mit dict.cc überein. Vor jemandem singen heißt einfach "sing in front of someone" was natürlich auch ein "to" impliziert. Wenn es denn eine Präposition sein soll, dann wäre das "für", denn da geht es tatsächlich nur um den Hörer, und nicht um die Position.

Comment: Ich kann vor 1000 Menschen für eine Person singen und andersrum. Der Adressat ist "für", die Position ist "vor"